# Angular ng-select menu with groups and ungrouped items

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

I have an Angular 10 project where I have a grouped ng-select menu which is part of a Reactive Form:

```
<ng-select
  [items]="lockerBanks"
  [selectOnTab]="true"
  [clearable]="true"
  bindLabel="label"
  bindValue="value"
  formControlName="lockerBanks"
  labelForId="lockerBanks"
  appendTo="body"
  groupBy="lockerType"
>
</ng-select>
```

Part of this form:

```
  form = this.fb.group({
    lockerBanks: [null]
  });
```

the grouped items are coming from an array of objects:

```
  lockerBanks = [
    { label: 'Eastside 1', value: 'eastside1', lockerType: 'Standard' },
    { label: 'Eastside 2', value: 'eastside2', lockerType: 'Standard' },
    { label: 'North Entrance', value: 'northentrance', lockerType: 'Climate Controlled' },
    { label: 'South Entrance', value: 'southentrance', lockerType: 'Climate Controlled' }
  ];
```

However, I need to add a static menu item to the top of the menu e.g. "Use Any Available" and I am unsure how to add a static item to this menu, and get the value when the static item is selected.

[Here's a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/smlombardi-ngselect-groups?) of what I have so far.

Comment: I think you can simply add an additional item (first in array) without a lockerType..?

Comment: That seems to work, thanks  I wish I could add it to the HTML template though, so I could add things to the end like the length of the lockerBanks ("Use Any Available (4)").

Comment: You potentially could. You can provide your own little templates with ng-select (pretty powerful). Not very well documented, however you can get a lot from the actual source code. Here are a few examples: https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates

Comment: But besides that, you could preprocess the options in your TS anyway. Find the length first, then programmatically add the item to the array.